# how can I loop macros in pyspark like in SAS?

Tags: loops, pandas, macros, pyspark

I want to iterate the same code for different macro sets like in SAS and then append all tables populated together. As I am coming from sas background, I am quite confused about how to do this in Pyspark environment. Any help is much appreciated!

Example code is below :

## STEP1: define macro variables

```
lastyear_st=201615
lastyear_end=201622

thisyear_st=201715
thisyear_end=201722
```

## STEP2: loop the code through various macro variables

```
customer_spend=sqlContext.sql("""
select a.customer_code, 
sum(case when a.week_id between %d and %d then a.spend else 0 end) as spend
from tableA
group by a.card_code
"""
%(lastyear_st,lastyear_end)
(thisyear_st,thisyear_end))
```

## STEP3: append each of the dataset populated above to the base table

Answer (score 1):

```
# macroVars are your start and end values arranged as list of list.
# where each innner list contains start and end value 

macroVars = [[201615,201622],[201715, 201722]]

# loop thru list of list ==> 
for start,end in macroVars:

    # prepare query using the values of start and end
    query = "SELECT a.customer_code,Sum(CASE\
    WHEN a.week_id BETWEEN {} AND {} \
    THEN a.spend \
    ELSE 0 END) \
    AS spend FROM tablea GROUP  BY a.card_code".format(start,end) 

    # execute query
    customer_spend = sqlContext.sql(query)

    # depending on your base table setup use appropriate write command for example  

    customer_spend\
     .write.mode('append')\
     .parquet(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))
```

Comment: Hi Pushkr, thanks for this. Can I also use string values within lists? So I mean, can it be something like [['a','b','c'] , [1,2,'x]] etc. ?

Comment: Yes you can use strings too

Comment: can i also define a macro variable out of the array separately and refer it within the array such as :   a= """case when spend>0 then 1 else 0 end"""   [[a,1,2],[a,2,4]]

Comment: I think you can. For example, you can write `a = 1 if spend >0 else 0` then use a in array/list like `macroVar = [[a,1,2],[a,2,4]]`

Comment: @Pushkr, how can I extend this if I have more then 1 query, like if I want to create a query that is FROM the result of customer_spend?